# TestServer With Azure Function .Net Core 2.2/3.0 returns 404

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, integration-testing

I’ve been trying hard at getting a unit test project adjacent to a Functions project to use TestServer. There are a few suggest out there but none have worked. I’d like to get the very basics in place where a vanilla function can get hosted and called using TestServer. Has anybody done it?

Here is what I have done: https://github.com/vedeja/azure-function-test-server

Comment: Can you please tell what you have followed and how you have setup TestServer and AzureFunction? This [link](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/serverless-webapi-hosting-aspnetcore-webapi-in-azure-functions/) defines the steps what you may be seeking.

Comment: Thanks @user1672994. I have seen that article and other similar ones, but kind of rejected them because it felt wrong to "host a web api in a function", since that is not what I want. But maybe it holds details to what I want. Let me try that a little more and get back. I did not follow any specific guide since I have not found one, but just used details from all around.

Comment: If you can post the steps and code which you have incorporated then it would be easy to understand by other SO users to respond. Otherwise, the current description of your problem is like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: Of course. But I'd rather find a vanilla guide to hosting and invoking functions using TestServer first - if there is one. That's why I did not want to go in to the fragmented result of my trial and errors. If there is none, I will provide my code.

Comment: There it is @user1672994, I've created a repo with the repro.

Comment: https://github.com/kmughal/IntegrationTestAzureFunc is having similar trouble. The main issue is that the normal Functions host handles controller/function discovery and activation for you. TestServer doesn't know about that, you need to hard code that. Let me experiment.

Comment: The Functions endpoints are different enough from normal MVC controllers that wiring them up manually is impractical. This is going to need some support from Functions directly.

Comment: Actually their testing docs aren't bad. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function